Non-negative Maclaurin coefficients on $(0,a)$ implies convexity
I was interested in Putnam 2003, A3: find the minimum of
$$|\sin(x)+\cos(x)+\tan(x)+\cot(x)+\sec(x)+\csc(x)|$$ for all real numbers $x$ (but it suffices to look over $(0,\pi/2)$, in which case $|\cdot|$ is not needed).
Denote the function to be minimized by $f(x)$. Clearly $f$ is symmetric on $(0,\pi/2)$; if we could show it is convex, then it would have a unique minimum, in fact at the midpoint $x=\pi/4$. To that end, write the relevant series:
$$
\sin(x) = x - \frac{1}{6}x^3+\cdots
$$
$$
\cos(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{2}x^2+\cdots
$$
$$
\tan(x) = x + \frac{1}{3}x^3+\cdots
$$
$$
\cot(x) = \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{3}x-\frac{1}{45}x^3-\cdots
$$
$$
\sec(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \cdots
$$
$$
\csc(x) = \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{6}x + \frac{7}{360}x^3+\cdots
$$
$$
f(x) = \frac{2}{x}+2+ \frac{11}{6}x+\frac{59}{360}x^3+O(x^4)
$$In fact, carrying out the asymptotics for one more term, it's not terrible that the fourth-order term of $f(x)$ is $\frac{1}{4}x^4$. So then $f(x)$ looks like $2/x$, which is convex, plus what is essentially a polynomial whose second-derivative on $(0,\pi/2)$ is clearly non-negative. Since the sum of two convex functions is clearly convex, we are done.

If all the coefficients are positive than you can claim it is convex, but the problem is showing $\textbf{all}$ of them are...
I considered a different approach for the question, denote
\begin{align*}
& u = \sin{x} + \cos{x} \\
& \sin{x}\cos{x} = \frac{u^2 -1}{2}
\end{align*}
hence
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \left|\sin{x}+\cos{x}+\tan{x}+\cot{x}+\sec{x}+\csc{x}\right| \\
&= \left|\sin{x}+\cos{x}+\frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{x}}+\frac{\cos{x}}{\sin{x}}+\frac{1}{\cos{x}}+\frac{1}{\sin{x}}\right| \\
&= \left|\frac{\sin^2{x}\cos{x}+\sin{x}\cos^2{x}+\sin^2{x}+\cos^2{x}+\sin{x}+\cos{x}}{\sin{x}\cos{x}}\right| \\
&= \left|\frac{\sin{x}\cos{x}(\sin{x}+\cos{x})+1+(\sin{x}+\cos{x})}{\sin{x}\cos{x}}\right| \\
&= \left|\frac{\left(\frac{u^2-1}{2}\right)u+1+u}{\frac{u^2-1}{2}}\right| = \left|\frac{u^3-u+2+2u}{u^2-1}\right| = \left|\frac{u^3+u+2}{(u-1)(u+1)}\right| \\
&= \left|\frac{(u+1)(u^2-u+2)}{(u+1)(u-1)}\right| = \left|\frac{u^2-u+2}{u-1}\right| = \left|u+\frac{2}{u-1}\right|
\end{align*}
now check that the function $g(u) = \left|u+\frac{2}{u-1}\right|$ attains the minimum at $u=1-\sqrt{2}$, so we are left to see if there is a solution to
$$
\sin{x}+\cos{x} = 1-\sqrt{2}
$$
but this equation is the same as
$$
\sqrt{2}\sin{\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)} = 1-\sqrt{2}
$$
since $\left|\frac{1-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right| < 1$, then there is $x \in \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies the equation above, hence the minimum is
$$
\left|1-\sqrt{2}+\frac{2}{-\sqrt{2}}\right| = 2\sqrt{2} -1.
$$

This is an interesting approach, but it's not quite correct, as you can see here.

@SammyBlack I did not say that $\frac{\pi}{4}$ is where the minimum is attained but that the minimum value is attained at a solution of $\sqrt{2}\sin{(x+\pi/4)} = 1-\sqrt{2}$, so the minimum value is $2\sqrt{2} -1$, if you plot  $y = 2\sqrt{2} -1$ in your graph you will se that this is the case

You're absolutely correct, my mistake. And you can see these minima here.

$$f(x)=\sin(x)+\cos(x)+\tan(x)+\cot(x)+\sec(x)+\csc(x)$$
$$x=2 \tan ^{-1}(t) \qquad \implies \qquad g(t)=\frac{2 t^4-3 t^3+3 t^2+t+1}{-t^4+t^3-t^2+t}$$
$$g'(t)=\frac{-t^6+2 t^5+9 t^4-4 t^3+t^2+2 t-1}{t^2 \left(t^3-t^2+t-1\right)^2}$$
Factoring
$$g'(t)=-\frac{\left(t^2+2 t-1\right) \left(t^4-4 t^3-1\right)}{t^2 \left(t^3-t^2+t-1\right)^2}$$
So, tthe quadratic
$$t^2+2 t-1=0 \qquad \implies \qquad t=-1\pm\sqrt{2}$$
The quartic seems more problematic even if the solutions are explicit. The discriminant shows that only two are real. By a quick inspection, one is negative and the other is close to $t=4$.
So the choice is more than limited : $t=\sqrt 2 - 1$ then $x=\frac \pi 4$ and a minimum value of $\left(2+3 \sqrt{2}\right) $.

$$f(x)=\sin(x)+\cos(x)+\tan(x)+\cot(x)+\sec(x)+\csc(x)$$
$$f'(x)=-\sin (x)+\cos (x)-\csc (x) (\cot (x)+\csc (x))+\sec (x) (\tan (x)+\sec (x))$$
Multiply by $\sin^2(x)\,\cos^2(x)$ to have everything in terms of powers of these to obtain
$$\frac{1}{8} (\sin (x)+\cos (x)+1)^2 (\sin (x)+\sin (3 x)-\cos (x)-4 \cos (2   x)+\cos (3 x))=0$$
So, since $x\in \left(0,\frac \pi 2\right)$, we are just concerned by the long term.
Let
$$g(x)=\sin (x)+\sin (3 x)-\cos (x)-4 \cos (2   x)+\cos (3 x)$$
By inspection $g(0)=-4$ and $g\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)=4$.
So, the line joining these two points give  an estimate of $\frac{0+\frac{\pi }{2}}{2}=\frac \pi 4$.
Compute $g\left(\frac{\pi }{4}\right)$ for the nice surprize !

I understand now that the approach using Maclaurin series is probably flawed. However, I believe there is a very clean approach to this problem that differs from the answers mentioned.
The goal is to show $f(x)$ is convex on $(0,\pi/2)$; it is clearly symmetric, so then it would have a unique minimum at $x=\pi/4$. Write
$$f_1(x) = \tan(x)+\cot(x);\, f_2(x) = \sin(x)+\csc(x);\, f_3(x) = \cos(x)+\sec(x)$$
Clearly $f(x)=f_1(x)+f_2(x)+f_3(x)$. We have $$f_1''(x)=2\tan(x)\sec^2(x)+2\cot(x)\csc^2(x)>0$$
For $f_2$, $$f_2''(x) = \cot^2(x)\csc(x) + \csc^3(x)-\sin(x) > \csc^3(x)-\sin(x)>\csc(x)-\sin(x)>0;$$
Similarly,
$$f_3''(x) = \tan^2(x)\sec(x)+\sec^3(x)-\cos(x)>0$$
Since their second derivatives are positive, each $f_i$ is convex; then $f$ is convex, as the sum of convex functions, and we are done.
